# Should I subtract the constant for least square

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, least-squares

Assume $Y=  Ax+b$ where $A$ is m $\times$  n matrix and $b$ is  n $\times$ 1 vector. I want to find the least square solution to this problem. I know it can be found as $A\backslash Y$ but should I first subtract $ b $ from $Y$ and then type $A\backslash Y$ or no subtraction is needed ?

Comment: What do you want to denote with $A\Y$ ?

Comment: Probably $A^{-1}Y$ as performed in Matlab

Comment: I assume that \ denotes the Matlab backslash operator, although the question should state this explicitly. The command x = A\b in Matlab computes a least squares solution to Ax=b. Of course, the expression x= A\(Y-b) computes a least squares solution to Ax=Y-b.

Comment: Usually $b$ is also unknown.

Comment: @YvesDaoust In my case assume b is known

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\min_x \| Y-Ax-b \|^2$$
Differentiating and equate it to zero, we have
$$2A^T(Y-Ax-b)=0$$

$$(A^TA)x=A^T(Y-b)$$

Hence yes, do subtract by $b$ provided you know $b$ in advanced.